# why does the navigation go to another in vaadin when i use navigator?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

when i tried to go to another page using navigator he always go to this page, and if someone could help me with this:

```
http://localhost:8080/#!/index
```

**and here is the code:**

```
 @SpringUI(path = "/")
 public class Mainview extends UI implements View {`

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    VerticalLayout contents = new VerticalLayout();
    setContent(contents);

    TextField username = new TextField("Email OR User Name");
    username.setWidth("25%");
    contents.addComponent(username);
    contents.setComponentAlignment(username, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

    TextField password = new TextField("password");
    password.setWidth("25%");
    contents.addComponent(password);
    contents.setComponentAlignment(password, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

    Button signButton = new Button("Sign In");
    signButton.setWidth("15%");
    contents.addComponent(signButton);
    contents.setComponentAlignment(signButton, Alignment.BOTTOM_CENTER);

    signButton.addClickListener(clickEvent -> {
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(getUI(), this);
        navigator.addView("/", new Mainview());
        navigator.addView("/index", new SecondPage());
        navigator.navigateTo("/index");
    });
}
}
```

**and here is the other page:**

```
@SpringUI(path = "/index")
public class SecondPage extends UI implements View {
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    VerticalLayout contents = new VerticalLayout();
    setContent(contents);
    Button button = new Button("hey");
    button.setWidth("10%");
    button.setHeight("10%");

    contents.addComponent(button);
}
```

thank's for the helpers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is quite simple, the other `UI` is deployed at URL http://localhost:8080/index not http://localhost:8080/#!/index. You seem to have a misconception about `Navigator`. `Navigator` is made for within `UI` navigation, i.e. navigation between `View`'s, not between `UI`'s.

I assume you actually do not want to define the `SecondPage` as another `UI`, but as another view. So you should not extend `UI` there. Also as you are using Spring DI there, you should define it as `@SpringView`. And as you do so, you do not need to register it via `Navigator.addView(..)` method, since Spring add-on will auto register all `@SpringView` annotated views to view provider automatically. So you should just autowire the view provider and set the view provider of the `Navigator`.

There is more documentation with examples here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-spring.html